# Ошибка с inline меню в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Выскакивает при нажатии на `callback_data` равному "England" такая ошибка: `markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}")) NameError: name 'team' is not defined`

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["leagues"])
async def football_leagues(message: types.Message):
    football_leagues = [
    (emoji.emojize(":England:") + " Англия, Премьер-лига           ", "England"),
    (emoji.emojize(":England:") + " Англия, Чемпионшип             ", "England-2"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Spain:") + " Испания, Примера                  ", "Spain"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Spain:") + " Испания, Сегунда                    ", "Spain-2"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Germany:") + " Германия, Бундеслига           ", "Germany"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Germany:") + " Германия, 2-я Бундеслига    ", "Germany-2"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Italy:") + " Италия, Серия А                       ", "Italy"),
    (emoji.emojize(":Italy:") + " Италия, Серия B                       ", "Italy-2")
    ]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for league, league_cd in football_leagues:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(league, callback_data=f"prefix:{league_cd}"))
    await message.answer("Лиги:", reply_markup=markup)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="prefix")
async def teams(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    data = callback.data.split(":")[1]
    await callback.answer()
    if data == "England":
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
        await callback.answer("Лиги:", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        await callback.message.answer("Выберите чемпионат Англии")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["teams_of_England"])
async def teams_of_England(message: types.Message):
    teams_of_England = [
    ("Манчестер Сити", "man-city"),
    ("Манчестер Юнайтед", "man-united"),
    ("Ливерпуль", "liverpool")
    ]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for team, team_cd in teams_of_England:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
    await message.answer("Англия, Премьер-лига:", reply_markup=markup)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="prefix")
async def teams(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    data = callback.data.split(":")[1]
    await callback.answer()
```

Comment: А что такое `team`?

Comment: @
oleksandrigo, в условии происходит эта ошибка

Comment: Я это понял, я спрашиваю зачем вы создаете эту ошибку, написав `teams`? Где вы хотите взять эту переменную?

Comment: @oleksandrigo, то есть чтоб вызвать меню эта строчка кода ```markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))``` не нужна?

Comment: Нет, она то нужна, просто что это за переменная `team`? Вам же ошибка так и говорит, что такой переменной нет

Comment: @oleksandrigo, я ж разделяю по префиксу ```teams_of_England``` на ```team``` и ```team_cd```. Может проблема в том, что содержимое ```callback_query_handler``` одинаковое?

Comment: @oleksandrigo, я вызываю inline меню ```football_leagues```, а дальше если нажатие происходит по "England" должно открываться новое inline меню ```teams_of_England```, но оно не открывается и как раз выбивается та ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, стоит попробовать сделать так:

```
    for i in teams_of_England: 
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(i[0], callback_data=f"prefix:{i[1]}"))
```